# Something stange in /etc/rc0.d

Tags: ubuntu, runlevel

I use Ubuntu 12.04.1
I just wanted to find good tool for managing services, and I see that it is not existing...
Native "update-rc.d" managing services, but don't provide information, and not native "chkconfig" provide information, but throw error when I try to activate some service in some run level.
Any way, I just listed /etc/rc0.d/ directory, and found start up link for networking script (link starting with "S"):

```
user@comp:/etc/rc0.d$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 окт.  11 16:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 139 root root 12288 окт.  21 11:55 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    17 окт.  11 16:45 K09apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 окт.  11 04:39 K10unattended-upgrades -> ../init.d/unattended-upgrades
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    27 окт.  11 04:39 K20speech-dispatcher -> ../init.d/speech-dispatcher
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   353 июля  26 20:23 README
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    18 окт.  11 04:39 S20sendsigs -> ../init.d/sendsigs
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    17 окт.  11 04:39 S30urandom -> ../init.d/urandom
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    22 окт.  11 04:39 S31umountnfs.sh -> ../init.d/umountnfs.sh
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    20 окт.  11 04:39 S35networking -> ../init.d/networking
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    18 окт.  11 04:39 S40umountfs -> ../init.d/umountfs
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    20 окт.  11 04:39 S60umountroot -> ../init.d/umountroot
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    14 окт.  11 04:39 S90halt -> ../init.d/halt
```

My only question: Is it OK?
If it OK, why should networking service start in halt run level?
If it not OK, how I fix it?

Comment: I am not familiar with Ubuntu, but it most likely that Ubuntu also switches to `systemd` management of services

Comment: I tried to find command and package, no one of them...

Comment: Ubuntu uses [Upstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto) as its _init_ process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `/etc/init.d/halt`. This file surely belongs in `/etc/rc0.d` - and the only thing it defines is the `stop` functionality (i.e. `/etc/init.d/halt start` is a no-op). We can hence assume that scripts in `/etc/rc0.d` are called with the `stop` rather than `start` argument.

Then having a look at `/etc/init.d/networking`, we see:

```
stop)
    check_network_file_systems
    check_network_swap

    log_action_begin_msg "Deconfiguring network interfaces"
    if ifdown -a --exclude=lo $verbose; then
        log_action_end_msg $?
    else
        log_action_end_msg $?
    fi
    ;;
```

which first makes sure that no filesystems are mounted on the network anymore (which should be the case after `umountnfs.sh` ran) and then disables networking (via `ifdown`) to, for example, release DHCP leases or anything else sensibly one would want to do upon network deconfiguration.

To conclude, having a link to `/etc/init.d/networking` in `/etc/rc0.d` is perfectly fine.

(Note that I use Debian, but the scripts should essentially be the same.)

Furthermore, you should normally use `update-rc.d`, which is able of enabling/disabling services, either for specific runlevels or in general, and `ls` in order to see which services are enabled/disabled. I guess Ubuntu won’t switch to systemd any time soon, although one can apparently install it in Debian already, if one choses to do so.

Comment: Unfortunately I changed computer, but I sure that your explanation answering to my question. Thank you very much.